# pandas simple loop with KeyError: 8167

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am trying to parse a column of semicolon separated cells. The column looks like the following:

```
Operations
ANALYSIS; LABEL; MANUFACTURE; PACK; STERILIZE
ANALYSIS; LABEL; PACK; STERILIZE
API MANUFACTURE
```

Now I am writing a simple loop to parse this column into unique list:

```
a=list()
for i in range(9552):
    a+=ops_list[i].split(";")
```

Pandas spits out error such as the following:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-aab8f3fc6761> in <module>
      1 a=list()
      2 for i in range(9552):
----> 3     a+=ops_list[i].split(";")

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4318         try:
   4319             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4320                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4321         except KeyError as e1:
   4322             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 8167
```

However, if I am simply printing out within each loop such as the following:

```
a=list()
for i in range(9552):
    print(ops_list[i].split(";"))
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `tolist`:

```
a=list()
for i in range(9552):
    a+=ops_list.tolist()[i].split(";")
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and all. I just found out that it was because the dataframe needed to be reindexed...... Row labels at around 8900 were messed up..... Ifixed that so now it is okay. But why tolist() function as a suggestion here though?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the input data frame needed to be reindexed. I just changed the index number and now it works.....

Comment: @Georgy Questions with upvoted answers cannot be deleted by the OP.